# AWS Glue / Spark - AnalysisException Cannot resolve column name after Filter -> Left Join

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I am trying to do filter and left join operations on some CSV files from AWS Glue 2.0 with pySpark. Sometimes, if the filter filters out all data or if the input csv is empty my job crashes with:

`AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "col_a" among ();'`

-I have seen this exception occurring for other people on a number of other questions, but I think my issue is losing the header information when the rows are removed -> is this a DynamicFrame feature (could not find anything about it in the aws glue docs)?

-I realise that I could do the filters after all the joins but wanted to avoid this because it seems like it might be more expensive, and because ideally I would like the job to also not crash if the input data was an empty CSV.

-Any suggestions greatly appreciated :)

Here is a mock of the pySpark code (please note that in the real thing I would like to chain together many joins, transforms and filters):

````
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db_name", table_name = "table_1", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")
DataSource1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db_name", table_name = "table_2", transformation_ctx = "DataSource1")

Table_1_Renames = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource0, mappings = [("col_a", "string", "col_a", "string"), ("col_b", "string", "col_xyz", "string")], transformation_ctx = "Transform0")
Table_2_Renames = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource1, mappings = [("col0", "string", "col0_renamed", "string"), ("col1", "string", "col1_renamed", "string")], transformation_ctx = "Transform1")

Table_1_Filter = Filter.apply(frame = Table_1_Renames, f = lambda row : (bool(re.match("KeepValue", row["col_b"]))), transformation_ctx = "Table_1_Filter")

Table_1_Filter_DF = Table_1_Filter.toDF()
Table_2_Renames_DF = Table_2_Renames.toDF()

#If the original data was empty, or the filter removes all rows of the data, we get:
#AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "col_a" among ();'
LeftJoin_1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(Table_1_Filter_DF.join(Table_2_Renames_DF, (Table_1_Filter_DF['col_a'] == Table_2_Renames_DF['col0_renamed']), "left"), glueContext, "LeftJoin_1") ```
````

Comment: Have you tried doing the filtering and joining within a Pyspark dataframe and not jumping back and forth to glue dynamic frames? I suspect that would work. I can show some example code if needed.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response - I have been on holiday. Example code would be much appreciated, that does sound worth trying.